# Writing convolution in other terms

Tags: convolution

Could I get some help with this question. I just started convolution and I'm still not clear on a lot of things

[image]

Comment: Try a change of variable of some form. I can't say more than this, it's a one liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the change of variables, let $x=-\tau-b$, then we have $\tau=-x-b$ and $dx=-d\tau$. Hence

$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\nu(t)&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\chi(x) h(-x-b+at)\ dx\\
&=&y(at-b).
\end{eqnarray*}$

Comment: shouldn't that be -dx

Comment: I was really over complicating things

Comment: I switched the lower and upper bound at the first step, so cancelled the minus sign.